# Org Babel Source Block Native Fontification

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to get org-babel source blocks to do native syntax highlighting. I've set `org-src-fontify-natively` to true, but am still not seeing anything.

Here's my related config:

```
(setq org-babel-default-header-args
  '((:session  . "none")
    (:results  . "replace")
    (:exports  . "code")
    (:cache    . "no")
    (:noweb    . "yes")
    (:hlines   . "yes")
    (:tangle   . "yes")
    (:padnewline . "yes")))

(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((emacs-lisp . t)
   (R          . t)
   (js         . t)
   (clojure    . t)
   (org        . t)
   (sh         . t)
   (python     . t)
   (dot        . t)
   (prolog     . t)
   (lisp       . t)
   ))

(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0   
      org-src-tab-acts-natively   t        
      org-src-fontify-natively    t        
      org-confirm-babel-evaluate  nil      
      org-src-window-setup 'current-window 
      org-src-preserve-indentation t
      org-src-strip-leading-and-trailing-blank-lines t
      )
```

And here's the `org-babel-view-src-block-info` (C-c C-v I):

```
Lang: emacs-lisp
Properties:
    :header-args    nil
    :header-args:emacs-lisp     nil
Header Arguments:
    :cache      no
    :exports    code
    :hlines     yes
    :lexical    no
    :noweb      yes
    :padnewline yes
    :results    none
    :session    none
    :tangle     yes
```

And my `(emacs-version)`:
`GNU Emacs 25.1.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1603))
 of 2016-04-03`